# JavaFX ListView: Couldn't add a Label to ListCell

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on chat app using JavaFX. I have a `ListView` that contains connected users. Each cell is represented by `UserView` object:

```
public class UserView {

    private Utilisateur user; //user
    private String avatar;// user's avatar
    private int numberofmessage = 0; //number of received messages.

    public UserView(Utilisateur user, String avatar) {
        this.user = user;
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }

    public Utilisateur getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(Utilisateur user) {
        this.user = user;
    }


    public String getAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }

    public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }

    public int getNumberofmessage() {
        return numberofmessage;
    }

    public void setNumberofmessage(int numberofmessage) {
        this.numberofmessage = numberofmessage;
    }

    public void InscrementMessages(int nbr){
        this.numberofmessage +=nbr; 
    }


}
```

I want to add a `Label` that contain the number of received messages.
That's what I did:

```
usersList.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<UserView>, ListCell<UserView>>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<UserView> call(ListView<UserView> param) {
               ListCell<UserView> cell = new ListCell<UserView>(){
                   @Override
                   protected void updateItem(UserView item, boolean empty) {
                       super.updateItem(item, empty);

                       if(!empty){

                           Image img = new Image("/images/"+item.getAvatar());
                           ImageView imageView = new ImageView(img);
                           imageView.setFitHeight(65);
                           imageView.setFitWidth(65);
                           setGraphic(imageView);
                           setText(item.getUser().getNom()+" "+item.getUser().getPrenom());

                           lblMsg = new Label();
                           if(item.getNumberofmessage() == 0){
                               lblMsg.setText("");
                           }
                           else{
                               lblMsg.setText(String.valueOf(item.getNumberofmessage()));
                               lblMsg.getStyleClass().clear();
                               lblMsg.getStyleClass().add("newMsg");
                           }

                           getChildren().add(lblMsg);
                       }
                   }

               };
               return cell;
            }
        });
```

and for testing purposes i set the number of messages for each user to 10:

```
for (Utilisateur user : users) {
    if(!Helper.getInstance().getCurrentUser().equals(user)){
       UserView uv = new UserView(user, "man.png");
       uv.setNumberofmessage(10);
       connectedUser.add(uv);
       listConv.add(new UserConversation(uv));
    }    
}
```

This is the result :

[image]

Comment: List cell isn't really a parent and doesn't have a definite way of laying out its children. You might either set the amount directly on the cell's text, or set the graphics for a stack pane and do all the logic there (add image view and label there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to add the `Label` using `getChildren().add(lblMsg);` which is not a valid usage of `ListCell` (or of its parent `Labeled`). Any `Node` that you want to display should be set to the [`graphicProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#graphicProperty--) of the cell, if you want to display more than one nodes, you can set a container node (a `Parent`) as graphic and add the nodes to this parent.

While knowing this, there are several possible fixes possible:

```
HBox root = new HBox(5);
root.getChildren().addAll(imageView, lblMsg);
setGraphic(root);
```

Or you can add the number of users to the text:

```
setText(item.getUser().getNom()+" "+item.getUser().getPrenom() + " " + item.getNumberofmessage());
```

With this the CSS will be lost (`lblMsg`), so maybe for your needs it is the best to use two `Label`s:

```
HBox root = new HBox(5);
Label lblUserName = new Label(item.getUser().getNom()+" "+item.getUser().getPrenom());
root.getChildren().addAll(imageView, lblUserName, lblMsg);
setGraphic(root);
```

For all of these soultions you have to remove some of the lines in your code, but it is quite straightforward to do this, so I will not detail this part.

Comment: Thank you, i used the third solution you mentioned, and it works well.
Just another question: can you tell me how to align the label to the left of the cell?

Comment: `root .setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);` will align the whole `HBox` vertically center, horizontally left.